# Variation in critical point of a function

Tags: calculus

Consider a smooth function of the form $f(\alpha, x, y)$. Write the function as $f_{\alpha}(x,y)$.
Assume $x$ and $y$ are parameters over which we'd like to optimize $f_{\alpha}$ for each fixed $\alpha$. For each fixed $\alpha$, critical points $(x^*, y^*)$ are defined by the vanishing of $\partial_x f_{\alpha} (x^*, y^*) $ and $\partial_y f_{\alpha} (x^*, y^*) $.

The question is: how can we compute the partial derivative $\partial_{\alpha} x^*$. Presumably, I think the question is how does $x^*$ vary as $\alpha$ is allowed to vary. I don't quite understand the question, though. Any suggestions/hints?

Comment: Are you trying to find $x*,y*$ such that they vanish for each $\alpha$? Or given some particular $\alpha$, find $x*,y*$? In the latter case, $f_{\alpha}$ is just a function $g(x,y)$, meaning we can ignore $\alpha$ altogether.

Comment: Trying to find those $(x^*, y^*)$ for which the partial derivatives $\partial_x f_{\alpha}$ and $\partial_y f_{\alpha}$ simultaneously vanish for each $\alpha$.

Comment: Ah, in which case, consider $\alpha$ as some psuedo constant and check for critical points but make no assumptions about $\alpha$ except for what the constraints impose.

Comment: Yes, I get that. But the question is then to compute $\partial_{\alpha} x^*$. Presumably this means how does $x^*$ change when the pseudo-constant $\alpha$ changes. I don't quite understand what the problem is asking for/how to attempt it.

Comment: There is a reason why $x,y$ are called indendent variables. $x,y$ don't depend on $\alpha$.

Comment: They vary indepenently, unless you impose a condition like: $\alpha=t(x)$ or something similar.

Comment: I get that but the derivative of $x^*$ with respect $\alpha$. Again, presumably the question is asking how does this $x^*$ (first coordinate of a critical point) changes as $\alpha$ is changed. 

The question is very confusing.

Comment: Are you certain you posted the complete question? I feel like you are ommiting some crucial information, like a parameter or something. If not, then I am unsure what you are asking. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the  partial derivatives of $f_{a}(x,y)$ wrt to x and y  by $P(x,y; a)$ and $Q(x,y;a)$ respectively. Setting $P$ and $Q$ equal to zero (to define critical points) gives you  two equations in three variables. Visualize this as two surfaces in 3D space, whose intersection (typically) carves out a smooth curve  $C$ in space whose parametrized description is  $C=<x(a), y(a), a>$.
This parametrizes the critical point as a function of the pseudo-constant $a$. The derivative $\frac{dC}{da}= <x'(a), y'(a), 1>$ contains the answer you seek.

On the other hand, from multivariable calculus, you learn that the cross product of the 3D gradient vectors
$\vec T=\nabla P \times \nabla Q$ is also a tangent vector to this curve.

If you rescale $\vec T$ so that its last component equals $1$, then this modified $T$ equals $\frac{dC}{da}$.